# Username and password inputs filling with random information on page load

Tags: php, html, forms

I wrote register/login files using php. I have a index.php that contains two html forms a registration form with input boxes for username, password, reenter password, and email. Then I have a login form that has inputs for username and password. When someone completes the registration form and submits the form action calls reg_user.php this file sends an email with a "complete your registration" link.

When you click the link it redirects to complete_reg.php which checks DB credentials and if ok says "Thank you for registering, click the button below to login" ***This is where the problem occurs***. When you click the button it redirects back to the index.php so you can then fill in the login form but when the page loads the username and password inputs on both forms are already filled in with a username and password BUT the username is an old admin password I setup for WordPress which I don't use anymore nor do I have it installed and the old password for the same.

I am not using WordPress at all on my computer and there is no WP database in phpMyAdmin/MySQL so its a complete mystery to me where this info is coming from. I did a search on my entire project just to be sure I didn't accidentally include them in any of my code or definitions and it didn't find a thing. I didn't post any code because I am not sure what would be helpful. Just hoping maybe someone would know where I could start to figure this out. Here is the end of the complete-reg.php which I know is probably not helpful but who knows...

```
    echo '<form class="congrats" action="index.php">';

    echo '<h2>Your registration is complete, you can now login!<h2>';

    echo '<h3>Press the button below to go to the login page.<h3>';

    echo '<input type="submit" name="logbutton" value="Login"/>';

    echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Clean the browser's cache, and Browsing Data (at least I know this option is available on Chrome, probably in all other browsers too).

Comment: Also try adding an autocomplete=off attribute to the input elements... `<input name="txt_username" id="txt_username" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" />`

Comment: It sounds like something local to your browser. Try a different browser to confirm. If this is not the case, please include your index.php code as that is where the problem exists according to your description.

Comment: (Your code looks like it's from the '90s.) Rather than have a form post to index. why don't you attach Javascript to redirect to the login page. Without seeing your index.php code, it is guesswork, but I agree with others in suspecting your browser.

Comment: I normally do use listeners and javascript but when I am just in the testing phase I usually go as simple as possible. agreed I don't need the echos, just habit guess again just testing at the moment. I really don't want to turn off autocomplete because I use it to my advantage although I suppose I could turn it off and then back on after it loads?. You all may be right maybe it is my browser (just got home will give it a shot) If that's the case is there a way to programmatically clear browser datas?  How would I avoid this happening on someones browser when the site is live?

Comment: Yes you guys were right it was the browser, strange. So why would it fill out the inputs on ***my page*** when it loads but it doesn't do it when I go to a live website like my bank or something? And as for the autocomplete would you recommend turning that off, or is it just preference?

Comment: The only thing I can think of re browser is autocomplete. At some point in the past the url was used for something else that you filled in the data for. (Suspect this as it sounds like a test system you are using). As to turning off autocomplete, as a user I like having it so it would make me upset if I came to your page regularly and had to keep filling in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It seems to be a browser issue: try clearing your browser's data or using a different browser to validate that this is the case.
2. PHP doesn't need to echo HTML: you just include it outside of the PHP tags.
   e.g `echo '<form class="congrats" action="index.php">';` simply becomes `<form class="congrats" action="index.php">` outside of the PHP tags.
3. As others have noted, it would be more modern to redirect the user instead of making another form which they need to submit.